# Nested if Statements in Email Templates

Tags: email, email-templates

I am trying to use nested if statements in my email template, like the following:

```
{{if subscriber.promo_group}}
    <p>You are one of the first {{var subscriber.promo_group}} subscribers.</p>
{{/if}}

{{if subscriber.coupon_code}}
    <p>Use code {{htmlescape var=$subscriber.coupon_code}} for {{htmlescape var=$subscriber.discount_amount}} off.</p>
    {{if subscriber.partner_coupon_code}}
        <p>Or, code {{var subscriber.partner_coupon_code}} for {{htmlescape var=$subscriber.partner_discount_amount}} off at checkout.</p>
    {{/if}}
{{else}}
    {{if subscriber.partner_coupon_code}}
        <p>Use code {{htmlescape var=$subscriber.partner_coupon_code}} for {{htmlescape var=$subscriber.partner_discount_amount}} off at checkout.</p>
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

When I get my email, though, I get it like this:

```
You are one of the first 20 subscribers.

Use code XXXXX-QTEALK15 for $35 off.

Or, code XXXXX10OFF for 10% off at checkout.

{{else}}
Use code XXXXX10OFF for 10% off at checkout.

{{/if}}
```

Is it possible to use nested if statements in the Magento email templates?

Comment: If you found a solution, please share it with us.

Comment: i didn't find a solution; had to re-jigger the email to get around the issue :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the start of the `Varien_Filter_Template` class you will find the following two constants.

```
const CONSTRUCTION_DEPEND_PATTERN = '/{{depend\s*(.*?)}}(.*?){{\\/depend\s*}}/si';
const CONSTRUCTION_IF_PATTERN = '/{{if\s*(.*?)}}(.*?)({{else}}(.*?))?{{\\/if\s*}}/si';
```

In the regular expression of `CONSTRUCTION_IF_PATTERN` you will notice that it has the form of

> {{if condition}} TEXT GOES HERE {{else}} OTHER TEXT GOES HERE {{/if}}

So, unfortunately nesting `if` statements is not possible as the first matched  `{{/if}}` will be caught in the regular expression.

Although, the class offers something other than the `{{if}}` statements, the `{{depend}}` statement. It is almost the same as the `{{if}}` except it has no `{{else}}` functionality.

Luckily in your case, the nested conditions aren't complicated and can be done using `{{depend}}`. So you can have the following:

```
{{if subscriber.promo_group}}
    <p>You are one of the first {{var subscriber.promo_group}} subscribers.</p>
{{/if}}

{{if subscriber.coupon_code}}
    <p>Use code {{htmlescape var=$subscriber.coupon_code}} for {{htmlescape var=$subscriber.discount_amount}} off.</p>
    {{depend subscriber.partner_coupon_code}}
        <p>Or, code {{var subscriber.partner_coupon_code}} for {{htmlescape var=$subscriber.partner_discount_amount}} off at checkout.</p>
    {{/depend}}
{{else}}
    {{depend subscriber.partner_coupon_code}}
        <p>Use code {{htmlescape var=$subscriber.partner_coupon_code}} for {{htmlescape var=$subscriber.partner_discount_amount}} off at checkout.</p>
    {{/depend}}
{{/if}}
```

If it needs to be more complicated that this, it is best to just simplify your logic using a block class for the template.

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried nesting control statements like that, but one possible solution (though maybe a little more work than you desire) is to include a standard `.phtml` template inside your email template.

The core uses this feature, and it can be very handy for situations where you need to run some PHP inside your email templates.

Have a look at:

`app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html`

as well as:

`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml`

In the `order_new.html` template, check line 97 (or thereabouts), you'll see this call:

`{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}`

This call checks your layout files for the handle `sales_email_order_items`. In `sales.xml` you'll find this down near line 268. You'll see this loads in the template `email/order/invoice/items.phtml` (among other things).

It's all pretty standard Magento layout stuff from here. If you have a look at the `items.phtml` template, the first thing you'll notice is that it assigns the `$_order` variable. This is being passed through in the email template's layout handle as `order=$order`. Once you get into `items.phtml`, they're just assigning that variable using `$this->getOrder()`.