# If Condition with "==" in Email Template {{depend}}

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, template-directive

I am using simple if condition in email template.

```
{{depend order.delivery_time=="1"}}
Delivery Time: 10am To 2pm
{{/depend}}
{{depend order.delivery_time=="2"}}
Delivery Time: 2pm To 7pm
{{/depend}}
{{depend order.delivery_time=="3"}}
Delivery Time: 7pm To 10pm
{{/depend}}
```

**But every time it is printing 1st value i.e. Delivery Time: 10am To 2pm**

Can anyone tell me, how to check == in email template?

Comment: Use If in place of depend . follow this link - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/852/nested-if-statements-in-email-templates

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have used [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797394/magento-email-template-if-statements) this link. That answer from ʍǝɥʇɐɯ  worked.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot use logical expressions in `depend` (unfortunately neither in `if` as one comment suggested)

> - `{{depend X}}...{{/depend}}` output content in between only if variable X is true-ish (note that you cannot use logical expressions
>     here, just variables or methods on variables.

<sup>From this answer, which covers more details of template directives: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121510/243</sup>

So the only way I see to achieve what you are trying is to add three variables. For example:

in PHP code (probably best in an `load_after` observer):

```
$order->setData('delivery_time_1', $order->getDeliveryTime() == '1');
$order->setData('delivery_time_2', $order->getDeliveryTime() == '2');
$order->setData('delivery_time_3', $order->getDeliveryTime() == '3');
```

then in the email template:

```
{{depend order.delivery_time_1}}

Delivery Time: 10am To 2pm

{{/depend}}
{{depend order.delivery_time_2}}

Delivery Time: 2pm To 7pm

{{/depend}}
{{depend order.delivery_time_3}}

Delivery Time: 7pm To 10pm

{{/depend}}
```

Comment: How to add website filter in Magento 1, app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html