# How to use if else statement in email subject

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, transactional-mail

I have been trying to check a condition on subject section of magento's transactional email.

I'm trying to display order status on subject except for pending.

This is what i have tried so far.

```
{{if  order.status!="pending"}} {{var order.status}} {{else}} test {{/if}}
```

Unfortunately this is not working as expected. I'm always getting else condition.

I have no idea why this condition is not working

```
order.status!="pending"
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Piyush it's not explaining how to check for equality and non-equality..

Comment: you can not use logical expressions in  `if/depends` in email templates . check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/153505/20064

Comment: @Piyush But this says that it can be used in email templates : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/852/nested-if-statements-in-email-templates

Comment: you can use `if/else` for only `var = true/false` , it won't work with any logical expressions like `==` or `!=`

Comment: @Piyush is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: one solution is to set a variable based on order status from controller and then use in email template